# How to set the exit code when throwing an exception

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

MyScript.ps1:

```
exit 1
```

MyThrow.ps1:

```
throw "test"
```

Execution in PowerShell:

```
& ".\MyScript.ps1"
Write-Host $LastExitCode # Outputs 1

Clear-Variable LastExitCode

& ".\MyThrow.ps1"
Write-Host $LastExitCode # Outputs nothing
```

How do I set a proper exit code when throwing an exception?

Comment: Why not either `try/catch` the command, or clear `$lastexitcode` before the command and test if it's `$null` afterwards?

Comment: In the end the script is not executed from the PowerShell but from the task scheduler. Currently if the script throws an exception, the exit code in the task scheduler is 0.

Comment: Do you have access to the script? Best solution would be to properly trap the exceptions there and exit with a from the catch, or set a code to exit with at the end

Comment: wtf powershell, why you no set exit code on exception :)

Comment: note that Powershell's behavior is inconsistent with uncaught `throw` statements. `$LastExitCode` is left as 0, indicating success, but `$?` is set to `$False`, indicating failure.

Comment: @Tydaeus: Does that mean the only way to check what the exit code is following an uncaught `throw` would be to invoke PowerShell from some other process, such as the cmd console, then check the error code that was returned?

Comment: @SimonElms: note that this information is only valid for PS4 and lower. PS5 and higher default to exit code 1 if an exception is thrown. Hope you're not still stuck on PS4 or lower.

Comment: @SimonElms @D.R. in PowerShell 5 (I can't speak to PS4 or lower), as illustrated in this question, an uncaught exception will set exit code 1 *when interpreted from outside PowerShell*, but will not modify `LASTEXITCODE` within PowerShell. My error-handling practice within PowerShell has become to reset and check LASTEXITCODE and throw an exception if nonzero to convert it to a PowerShell exception, then wrap in a try/catch.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You don't. When you throw an exception you expect someone to handle it. That someone would be the one to terminate execution and set an exit code. For instance:

```psh
try {
  & ".\MyThrow.ps1"
} catch {
  exit 1
}
```

If there is nothing to catch your exception you shouldn't be throwing it in the first place, but exit right away (with a proper exit code).

Comment: What if you want to do a try catch finally? I would assume if you end up inside the catch then you would never hit the finally because of the exit.

Comment: As per @AnsgarWiechers' answer, a `finally` will always run even if the catch before it does an `exit 1`.

Comment: the implied best practice is that you use try/catch when calling PowerShell functions/scripts and check `LASTEXITCODE` when using non-PowerShell commands, and that your PowerShell functions/scripts use `exit` only if they're expected to be called from outside PowerShell.

Answer (score 24):

Becareful:

**With Powershell 4 and less:**

When an exception is thrown, exit code remains at **0** (unfortunately)

**With Powershell 5 and up:**

When an exception is thrown, exit code defaults to **1**

Comment: Upvoted, this is a much better answer nowadays. Maybe I should even change the accepted answer...don't know about the meta rules though.

Comment: in PowerShell 5 (I can't speak to PS4 or lower), as illustrated in this question, an uncaught exception will set exit code 1 *when interpreted from outside PowerShell*, but will not modify `LASTEXITCODE` within PowerShell. My error-handling practice within PowerShell has become to reset and check LASTEXITCODE and throw an exception if nonzero to convert it to a PowerShell exception, then wrap in a try/catch.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can set the code also with throw, just put it before throw.

Contents of the script: Throw.ps1

```
exit 222
throw "test"
```

Output:

```
PS C:\> .\Throw.ps1
PS C:\> $LASTEXITCODE
222
```

If you run it like this:

```
powershell .\Throw.ps1
```

The output will be as follows:

```
PS C:\> powershell .\Throw.ps1
PS C:\> $LASTEXITCODE
1
```

But here is the thing, powershell exit codes should be either 0 or 1,
anything else, finally will give you result of 1.

Another interesting thing to mention, if to try $? after you run the script,
if true or false, the result depends of what you want to put in there.
`exit 0 --> true`, `exit 1 --> false`

Here it is an example:

Content of the script: Throw_1.ps1

```
exit 1
throw "test"
```

Output:

```
PS C:\> .\Throw_1.ps1
PS C:\> $?
False
```

Content of the script: Throw_0.ps1

```
exit 0
throw "test"
```

Output:

```
PS C:\> .\Throw_0.ps1
PS C:\> $?
True
```

As you can see it is just what you need or want to achieve.

Comment: This doesn't set the exit code and throw. It sets the exit code and exits. Everything after the `exit` is unreachable code.

Answer (score 0):

Running the mythrow.ps1 inside powershell will set $? to false, and will add to the $error object array.  Running it with another powershell process will set $lastexitcode to 1.

```
PS C:\> powershell mythrow.ps1
PS C:\> $lastexitcode
1
```

Comment: See @Kino101 answer, this is only true for Power-shell 5+